# AG-Grid (Enterprise) Customising the General Menu Tab Callback not firing

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

Using Ag-grid Enterprise with Angular 13 and creating a custom General menu tab.

Ag grid gives a good example regarding creating the menu lines

```
const athleteMenuItems: (| MenuItemDef | string )[] = params.defaultItems.slice(0);
    athleteMenuItems.push({
      name: 'AG Grid Is Great',
      action: () => {
        console.log('AG Grid is great was selected');
      },
    });
```

However, setting the action to a component method other than "console.log" (defined in the example) causes an error when stepping through (but no console error.).

If I create a regular TS function and assign that.. it works, but I don't have access to the component (this binding ) or DI services.

This must be a common issue for Angular users but I can't find any guidence in the Ag grid docs.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

You need to provide the component context via ag grid options. Like this.

```
const gridOptions = {
   context: { thisComponent: this }
};
```

Then in the action block of your menuItem the context will be available via the passed params object

```
  athleteMenuItems.push({
      name: 'AG Grid Is Great',
      action: () => {
        // run a function here
        params.context.thisComponent.functionName();
      },
  });
```

Works for me.

Anyone who works for AG Grid, could notes how to grab the context be includined on that docu page.